# Why does encrypt, then decrypt give me a different output?

Tags: php, jquery, encryption, cryptojs

In my code I encrypt some data two times. First in jQuery:

```
var text = '' + CryptoJS.Rabbit.encrypt("12345", "PassPhrase");
```

then this is posted with ajax to php and encrypted again:

```
function mc_encrypt($encrypt, $key){
    $encrypt = serialize($encrypt);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $key = pack('H*', $key);
    $mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $encrypt, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
    $passcrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $encrypt.$mac, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $encoded = base64_encode($passcrypt).'|'.base64_encode($iv);
    return $encoded;
}
```

Afterwards, this is stored in a database. If a user wants to access the value again, I retrieve it from the database and then decrypt it:

```
function mc_decrypt($decrypt, $key){
    $decrypt = explode('|', $decrypt);
    $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt[0]);
    $iv = base64_decode($decrypt[1]);
    $key = pack('H*', $key);
    $decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
    $mac = substr($decrypted, -64);
    $decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -64);
    $calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $decrypted, substr(bin2hex($key), -32));
    if($calcmac!==$mac){ return false; }
    $decrypted = unserialize($decrypted);
    return $decrypted;
}
```

This is then posted back to the jQuery and decrypted again:

```
var text = CryptoJS.Rabbit.decrypt(text, "PassPhrase");
text = text.toString();
console.log(text);
```

However, the value logged in the console is quite different from the value ('12345') at the beginning. I don't know why this is happening and I've been looking at this problem for the last two days, yet I can't seem to figure out the problem...

Comment: First off why are you doing this? [Why is "double" encryption better?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32247/will-double-encryption-increase-the-security-of-cipher-vs-bruteforce)

Comment: if you get different values, then you didn't encrypt and/or decrypt properly. The functions don't care if everything is "right". they just take some data and do a bunch of math on it. If the math goes wrong, the functions don't care, they'll just do what they're told.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the input/output of just the PHP portion? Would help to isolate where the problem is

Comment: It's not that double encryption is better, it's that I don't want to send data unencrypted to a PHP file.

Comment: The PHP functions give me the same output and input, so the problem must be somewhere in the jQuery functions...

Comment: @user3740505 If your worried about the data being unencrypted during transport, Thats what SSL is for

Comment: Can you decrypt in jQuery with your encryption library?

Comment: "Yes, I can." - Barack Obama

Comment: After or before the round trip?

Answer (score 0):

CryptoJS.Rabbit.decrypt is returning a **word array**, and you are calling **toString** on it. For "12345" I would guess that the result you are seeing is "3132333435".

Use CryptoJS **stringify**, e.g. CryptoJS.enc.Utf16.stringify(text) or CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(text), depending on the original encoding.

You can choose the encoding on the way in by modifying your code like this, for example:

```
p = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("12345");
text = '' + CryptoJS.Rabbit.encrypt(p, "PassPhrase");
```

Then on the return trip:

```
var text = CryptoJS.Rabbit.decrypt(text, "PassPhrase");
text = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(text); // use same encoding as original input
console.log(text);
```